# Pandas 0.13.1 Python 3 ValueError Cannot convert Nan to integer

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I recently switched to python 3 from 2.7, reinstalled all my libraries and have been fixing scripts by hand without py2to3.
Part of my script which sorts odds and even got a `ValueError: Cannot convert Nan to integer`

```
import pandas as pd

def ExtractU(df):
   is_even = df['IDs'].str.extract('(\d+).*').astype(int) % 2 == 0
   Even=df[is_even]
   Odd=df[~is_even]
   return Odd
```

So to test this I changed it to print the dataframe using:

```
print (df['IDs'].str.extract('(\d+).*'))
```

and got an array of `Nan`s So I am guessing a `pandas` function might be deprecated because the regex does not work or it is because the version was downgraded from one of the developmental versions I was previously using.

How do I get it to return numerical values back?

So I redid the code in a smaller set and it works meaning something is wrong with the larger dataset.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['10A','6.5', '4 A', '3 1/2'], 'Name': ['J','K','L','M']})


def ExtractU(df):
    is_even = df['ID'].str.extract('(\d+).*').astype(int) % 2 == 0
    Even=df[is_even]
    Odd=df[~is_even]
    return Even

print (ExtractU(df))
```

So the print prior to the line just deletes duplicates `df=df.drop_duplicates(['Name','ID']).set_index('Name')` and if I print it gives:

```
           ID
Name        
Gary          6445
Jerry         6239
Anza          3828
Kang          3745
[28 rows x 1 columns]
```

I am not going to print the whole thing because it is similar. Both columns are data type objects and there are no `Nan` or strings. But once It goes to the next line `is_even = df['ID'].str.extract('(\d+).*').astype(int) % 2 == 0` it gives an `ValueError`.

Here is the error on console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 301, in runcode
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2018, in astype
    dtype, copy=copy, raise_on_error=raise_on_error)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 2416, in astype
    return self.apply('astype', *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 2375, in apply
    applied = getattr(blk, f)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 427, in astype
    values=values)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 444, in _astype
    values = com._astype_nansafe(self.values, dtype, copy=True)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py", line 2222, in _astype_nansafe
    return lib.astype_intsafe(arr.ravel(), dtype).reshape(arr.shape)
  File "lib.pyx", line 733, in pandas.lib.astype_intsafe (pandas\lib.c:12697)
  File "util.pxd", line 59, in util.set_value_at (pandas\lib.c:49357)
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

It should return a `bool` instead of the error

Comment: What's your question here? Is it why you're getting a `ValueError`, or what to do about it?

Comment: @TomAugspurger It worked fine before and there are no `Nan`s in the list. I am trying to get numerical values back.

Comment: @user3084006: Can you give a concrete example of what `df['IDs']` looks like, and how `ExtractU` used to behave?

Comment: @unutbu to answer this it would behave the same as the example in above just copy the code where the `df` is `df=pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['10A','6.5', '4 A', '3 1/2'], 'Name': ['J','K','L','M']}) `

Answer (score 1):

You could change

```
is_even = df['IDs'].str.extract('(\d+).*').astype(int) % 2 == 0
```

to

```
is_even = df['IDs'].str.extract('(\d+).*').astype(float) % 2 == 0
```

Since `NaNs` can be accommodated by `float` arrays, but not `int` arrays. Not however, that

```
In [150]: ser = pd.Series(['1','2','three'])

In [151]: is_even = ser.str.extract('(\d+).*').astype('float') % 2 == 0

In [152]: ser[~is_even]
Out[152]: 
0        1
2    three
dtype: object
```

So items that return `NaN`, like `'three'`, will be regarded as "odd".

---

By the way, `Even=df[is_even]` is computed but never used.

Comment: The only problem is there were no `Nan`s in the data set or strings like 'three'. This happened when I switched from python2.7 to 3

Comment: wait I just have to make a pandas dataframe with it.

Comment: @untubu I do not think this is a problem anymore it is a problem with another part of the code.

Comment: Yes, that's what it sounds like to me. You could use `np.where(pd.isnull(df['ID'].str.extract('(\d+).*')))[0]` to find the indices where `df['ID']` is mapping to `NaN`.

Comment: I tried it via printing on the dataset from a csv and it gives `Nan` Checked it and they were all numbers. So I have no idea what the problem is. But this happened only when I switched to Python 3 just today. I can switch back to 2.7. Do you think it is something to do with the data type conversion?

Comment: No, I wouldn't give up on Python3. Can you post the csv rows that are causing trouble? If we can reproduce the error, we can probably suggest a fix.

Comment: is there a way to check data types inside the `DataFrame` because I think the `.str.extract('(\d+).*').astype` function not working might be python3 switching the data type from string to object. since the `str.extract` gives me Nan and print gives me data

Comment: Ok I added the Error Traceback if it helps. The correct thing to return is a `bool` value